# Nifi > View Status History > How total task duration (ms) calculated and where does it stores on nifi server

Tags: apache-nifi

Right click on any process and click View Status History.

I need to know how total task duration (ms) calculated and where does it stores on nifi server ( in form of files)

Is it calculated dynamically / run-time or through any source file.

[image]

Comment: you can refer source code from here to understand NiFi internals better - https://github.com/apache/nifi

Comment: what is your object?  you can collect statistics via reporting tasks and rest api.